# How to assign SQL query result to variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need assign the following SQL Server's query result value to the variable called `@value1`

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
WHERE apo_id = '2589';
```

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Is `$value1` a variable in your client programming language?

Comment: no it is my own variable name

Comment: Variables, in SQL Server, are prefixed with an `@`, not a `$`. If you're trying to put the results set into a variable in your application code the things you should be tagging are the application code language, and included your existing application code.

Comment: `DECLARE @Var Datatype; SELECT @Var = Column FROM customer WHERE apo_id = '2589';` Note this won't work as expected if you have more than 1 row with the condition `apo_id = '2589'`

Comment: Considering the OP is using `*`, @Sami , I *suspect* they want to store *all* the columns (and rows?) into a single variable. Difficult to really know what they are after at the moment though.

Comment: We don't know really what he want to do @Larnu Thus I write `Column` instead of `*`

Comment: yes I need select multiple raws sometime

Comment: So you'll be putting multiple statements into a single variable, @mogasiru? Will those result sets all have the exact same definition?

Comment: [Declaring a variable of type table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#a-declaring-a-variable-of-type-table)

Answer (score 2):

1 - First declare your variable of type table.

```
declare @value1 table(
  --YOUR TABLE DEFINITION ex: ValueId int, 
)
```

2 - Insert into your variable

```
insert into @value1 select * from customer WHERE apo_id = '2589';
```

Hope that helps, thanks.

Comment: why you are declare table?

Comment: Since your return from query is a tabular return you need to declare a table to use as a return.

Answer (score 1):

It won't really be a variable but a table because you are selecting multiple fields (e.g. Select *) but, you can select INTO a temporary table like this:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #myTempTable 
FROM customer 
WHERE apo_id = '2589';
```